# How to get value of all same keys of multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Basically i want to loop through a multidimensional associative array to get a simple indexed array

**Here is my master array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 5
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 6
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 7
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 8
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 4
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 9
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [user_id] => 10
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [user_id] => 11
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [user_id] => 12
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [user_id] => 13
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**Here is the result i want to achive**

$userArray= array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
basically i just want all the user_id key value inside 1 single indexed array.

Till now i have tried this code

```
$keys = array_keys($masterArray);

for($i = 0; $i < count($masterArray); $i++) {

    echo $keys[$i] . "{<br>";

    foreach($masterArray[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {

        echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";

    }

    echo "}<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to travel recursively to collect all user IDs as below:

```
<?php

function collectUserIDs($data,&$result){
    foreach($data as $current_data){
        $result[] = $current_data['user_id'];
        collectUserIDs($current_data['children'],$result);
    }
}

$result = [];
collectUserIDs($data,$result);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: children
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
i am getting these errors while executing your script with my array .

Comment: @Zoobi Could you share a demo link of it? I don't see why that should happen?

Comment: Nope Vivek_23 i could not share a demo link cause i am working in local machine on xampp server

Comment: @Zoobi Could you share a demo using https://3v4l.org/ ? Or can you do `var_export()` of your array and share that in your post.

Comment: @Zoobi Never mind. I did it myself. It works perfectly fine. https://3v4l.org/pQLMA

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) which will iterate over the leaf nodes in a multidimensional array, check for the key being `user_id` and if so, add it to a list of ids...

```
$ids = [];
array_walk_recursive($masterArray, function ( $value, $key) use (&$ids)  {
    if ( $key == "user_id" )    {
        $ids[] = $value;
    }
});

print_r($ids);
```

which with the sample data, gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 9
    [8] => 10
    [9] => 11
    [10] => 12
    [11] => 13
)
```

Comment: how to get the array as indexed array not as an asssociative array i just want id's inside array without key .

Comment: The output array is exactly the same as `array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);`, the output shows a normal sequential array.